# Matrix dimensions for weight matrices in an LSTM

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement an LSTM Unit object using the following definition for the activations:

[image]

I wanted to confirm my shapes are correct. For intents and purposes, assume my data is some arbitrary time series data.

The input x^(t) has shape (1, input size)

I am not sure what the size of h^(t-1) would be. I'm assuming it is a column vector of shape (hidden size, 1). If so, why?

When column stacking (or concatenating) these two vectors, I should be getting a matrix of shape (hidden size, input_size). Is this correct? I'm also not entirely sure if there is a better reason outside of arithmetic in my head.

As a result I expect the weight matrices for each parameter i, f, o, and g to have shape (hidden size + input size, hidden size), but I'm not sure if this is correct either and it doesn't entirely make sense to me.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this answer but I'm posting it because I don't think you will get an answer here (maybe on Cross Validated or Data science stack exchange you might be luckier).

I think there is a confusion on your meaning of `input_size` because as far as I understand it the meaning is how many elements you have at time `t` and not the total length of your time series. If you have univariate time series, then `input_size=1`. But if you are dealing with text analysis then you could have 2 words at time `t` so that `input_size=2`. In multivariate time series with say 3 variables and 1 value per variable at time `t`, the shape would be `(3,1)`.

The shape of `h_(t-1)` is `(hidden_size,1)` because it's the Hadamard product of the output `o` at time `t` and `tanh(c)` at time `t`. This product is just component-wise multiplication between two vectors of the same size, so in particular `h^{t-1}` has the same shape as `o_t`. If you denote by `W_o` the weight matrix for the parameter `o` and `b_o` the biases vector for the parameter `o`, then

```
o_t=\sigma(W_f*[x_t,h_(t-1)] + b_o)
```

where `\sigma` is applied component-wise. So the shape of the matrix `W_f` is `(hidden_size,1+hidden_size)` and the shape of `b_o` is `(hidden_size,1)`.

When you concatenate `x_t` and `h_(t-1)`, the shape you get is `(1+hidden_size,1)`. The shape will be different if you have more than one value at time `t` and more than 1 variable in your time series, and in this scenario `h_(t-1)` becomes a matrix (check out an example using tensorflow here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent#lstm).

The shape of the weight matrices for `i,o,g,f` is `(hidden_size,1+hidden_size)`. You basically compute these values for each time period `t` in order to obtain the hidden state `h_t` and the cell state `c_t`. Every time you perform this step at time `t`, the cell state `c_t` is carrying the 'memory information' from previous values of your time series.

Again, I'm not sure about this answer but I hope it could be useful at least a little bit because I'm also trying to fully understand LSTM.

Comment: I am doubt about this order ("So the shape of the matrix W_f is (hidden_size,1+hidden_size)"). In my understanding the order should be  (hidden_size,hidden_size)